# Inverse Distance Weighted Python error in QGIS 2.0

Tags: python, error, qgis-2

When I wanto to use the command Inverse Distance Weighted in QGIS 2.0, I want to execute as batch process but when I open file it appears a window that say Error de Python

This is what it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchInputSelectionPanel.py",
>   line 70, in showSelectionDialog
>       self.text.setText(str(files[0])) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 71: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Python Version:

- 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS Version:

- 2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, ebebdf3

> Ruta de Python: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\Users\Genesis/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Users\Genesis/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

I am working with a shp file that contains a point list from a whatershed

Comment: What file format are you working with?  If it's text based, I would suggest converting the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: it is a shp file that contains a point list from a watershed

Comment: Check the attributes for any non UTF characters.  If there are too many, try removing all fields you don't need for the analysis.

Comment: @Geoist That's good advice. Given that a batch dialog has thrown this exception, one ought to suspect the problem may lie in the *name* of one of the files rather than in any of the attributes stored in those files.  The error message is clear: look for a file name (fully qualified, I suspect) containing the high-end ASCII character 0xf3 ("ó") as its 71st character.

Answer (score 3):

As whuber pointed, the problem its with the name of the file. Rename it without using accents or spaces or any non basic character.